# Shift from Cowboy to Phoenix

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, cowboy

I have a cowboy project with schemas and handlers specified. But, there is no support for sessions and CSRF protection in cowboy.

So, I need to shift this project to Phoenix. Phoenix uses cowboy as dependency and invokes `Plug.Adapter.cowboy.Handler`.

Is there any easy way to shift to Phoenix? I could not find support to migrate from cowboy to Phoenix.

Comment: I don't know of an easy was. Even though Phoenix uses cowboy they operate at different levels of abstraction. When using cowboy you have more control over a lot of things, while Phoenix does some of them for you. My guess the migration is necessarily manual.

Comment: Is there any way to call cowboy app's handler from phoenix controller when i have a cowboy only app and phoenix app in a single umbrella app? If i can achieve this, then i don't need to shift complete project to phoenix.